# Ошибка IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, gson

Есть код:

```
class ApiDataSourceIMPL(private val exchangeRateDataSource: ExchangeRateDataSource):
        ApiDataSource {
    
        override fun startMigration (context: Context) {
    
            val call = ApiClient.instance?.api?.loadExchangeRateApi()
            call?.enqueue(object: Callback<ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>>,
                    response: Response<ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>>
                ) {
                    // создаём список
                    var loadExchangeRate: ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>? = null
                    // очищаем массив
                    loadExchangeRate?.clear()
                    // получаем данные с сервера
                    loadExchangeRate = (response.body() as ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>?)!!
    
                    // помещение данных в локальную базу данных
                    for (audit in loadExchangeRate) {
    
                       // audit.id = 1
                        audit.id?.let {
                            ExchangeRateModel(
                                it,
                                audit.AUD.toString(),
                                audit.EUR.toString(),
                                audit.JPY.toString(),
                                audit.MDL.toString(),
                                audit.RUB.toString(),
    
                            )
                        }?.let {
                            exchangeRateDataSource.insert(
                                it
                            )
                        }
    
                    }
    
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ЗАГРУЗКА", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ОШИБКА! ВКЛЮЧИТЕ ИНТЕРНЕТ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
                }
            })
    
        }
    
    }
```

После выполнения всплывает Toast `ОШИБКА! ВКЛЮЧИТЕ ИНТЕРНЕТ!`, пробовал дебажить, доходит только до строки `call?.enqueue(object: Callback<ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>>` (сключительно), дальше переходит к "аварийному" сообщению

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связанно и как это исправить

Код ApiClient:

```
class ApiClient private constructor() {

    val api: ApiInterface
        get() = retrofit!!.create(
            ApiInterface::class.java)

    init {
        retrofit =
            Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

    }

    companion object {

        private val BASE_URL = "https://api.apilayer.com/"

        private var apiClient: ApiClient? = null
        private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

        val instance: ApiClient?
            @Synchronized get() {

                if (apiClient == null) {

                    apiClient =
                        ApiClient()
                }

                return apiClient

            }
    }
}
```

GET запрос:

```
@Headers("apikey: мой ключ")
@GET("exchangerates_data/latest?symbols=AUD%2CEUR%2CJPY%2CMDL%2CRUB&base=USD")
fun loadExchangeRateApi(): Call<ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>>
```

Интернет включен

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` в манифесте есть

даже запросы отправляются (в этом api количество запросов в месяц ограничено и, после запуска приложения, счётчик каждый раз увеличивается)

Использовав `Log.e("ApiDataSource", "onFailure", t)` получил:

```
2022-08-23 20:29:16.392 21052-21052/com.sem.exchangerate E/ApiDataSource: onFailure
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Json:

```
{
  "base": "USD",
  "date": "2022-08-23",
  "rates": {
    "AUD": 1.444127,
    "EUR": 1.00345,
    "JPY": 136.770153,
    "MDL": 19.351829,
    "RUB": 60.249987
  },
  "success": true,
  "timestamp": 1661277305
}
```

Модель для получения:

```
data class ExchangeRateApiModel (

    @SerializedName("id") @Expose
    var id: Int? = 1,

    @SerializedName("AUD") @Expose
    val AUD: Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("EUR") @Expose
    val EUR: Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("JPY") @Expose
    val JPY: Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("MDL") @Expose
    val MDL: Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("RUB") @Expose
    val RUB: Double? = null

)
```

модель для записи в базу данных:

```
@Entity(tableName = "exchange_rate_table")
class ExchangeRateModel(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id:Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "AUD")
    val AUD: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "EUR")
    val EUR: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "JPY")
    val JPY: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "MDL")
    val MDL: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "RUB")
    val RUB: String

)
```

// я пытался получать только значения валют

Comment: Туда где выводится тост `ОШИБКА! ВКЛЮЧИТЕ ИНТЕРНЕТ!`  добавьте печать ошибки: `t.printStackTrace()` - и смотрите в логах что напишет.

Comment: [Добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1442063/edit) стектрейс ошибки в ваш вопрос, распечатайте его с помощью `t.printStackTrace()` либо залоггируйте: `Log.e("ApiDataSource", "onFailure", t)`.

Comment: @Vadik, добавил, то, что вывелось в Logcat я добавил в вопрос

Comment: Неправильная модель для json: вы просите у ретрофита список объектов `ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>`, но приходит один объект. Не видя модели и json не могу сказать что она подходит, но список точно лишний.

Comment: @woesss, модели и json в вопрос добавил

Comment: Нельзя получить сразу вложенный объект - нужна модель для всего json, а после получения уже из неё брать всё что нужно. Вам нужен ещё один класс с полем `rates: ExchangeRateApiModel` и везде заменить `ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>` на этот новый класс.

Comment: @woesss, огромное Вам спасибо, оформите, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его принять

Comment: @Vadik, премного благодарен! Без Вашего комментария про Log  я бы не нашёл ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя получить сразу вложенный объект - нужна модель для всего json, а после получения уже из неё брать всё что нужно.
Вам нужен ещё один класс вида:

```kotlin
data class ExchangeRateResponseModel (
    @SerializedName("rates") @Expose
    val rates: ExchangeRateApiModel? = null
)
// при использовании Gson можно не объявлять поля, которые нас не интересуют
```

Далее везде заменить `ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>` на этот новый класс.